# why Hamiltonian can be expressed by sum of outer product in two level systems?

Tags: hamiltonian-simulation, projection-operator

[image: why H can be expressed by outer product of eigenkets in two level systems]

I can not figure out why Hamiltonian can be like this. Does H should be kinetic energy puls potential energy? Your help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: where is the text from?

Comment: Hi and welcome to Quantum Computing SE. Please avoid posting scans of documents. Use MathJax and citations instead.